# UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Cannot find module '/MyProject/node_modules/react-native-scripts/build/scripts/init.js'

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-native

I'm trying to build a new React Native project with the Facebook React Native tutorial. This command has worked for me before, but all of a sudden I now get this error message.

```
(node:14866) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Cannot find module '/MyProject/node_modules/react-native-scripts/build/scripts/init.js'
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:581:15)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:507:25)
at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:637:17)
at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:20:18)
at _callee2$ (/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/create-react-native-app/build/index.js:128:32)
at tryCatch (/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:62:40)
at Generator.invoke [as _invoke] (/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:296:22)
at Generator.prototype.(anonymous function) [as next] (/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:114:21)
at step (/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/babel-runtime/helpers/asyncToGenerator.js:17:30)
at /.config/yarn/global/node_modules/babel-runtime/helpers/asyncToGenerator.js:28:13
(node:14866) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:14866) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

I'm not sure what changed, but I'm unable to find a workaround. Can anyone help?

EDIT: The new way to start React Native app is found here: https://github.com/react-community/create-react-native-app

Answer is below.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Create React Native App has changed and now uses a new Expo CLI.

I followed the instructions here: https://github.com/react-community/create-react-native-app

```
$ npm install -g expo-cli
$ expo init AwesomeProject
$ cd AwesomeProject
$ expo start
```

It will now open up a new localhost Metro Bundler that has a GUI that allows you to run your simulator, send link, or publish your project.

Comment: I have done the same as this. worked fine. but after ejecting the code, giving me error "bundling failed: NotFoundError: Cannot find entry file index.js in any of the roots"

Comment: they're changing something everytime. this is bad. all documents are using create-react-native-app in the web. I hate that the javascript world is changing everytime and all documents become outdated.

Comment: @KedarDave I posted a solution to that here:  https://github.com/wix/react-native-navigation/issues/314#issuecomment-426770444

Comment: React-Native changes are so big, its like learning react-native again. Not sure why they made easy stuff so complicated.

Answer (score 0):

These javascript libraries are changing rapidly. If you are using yarn, This worked for me in 2020 for macOS

```
brew install yarn
sudo yarn global add expo-cli
expo init <project name>
```

Then a project will be created under the name of

```
cd <project name>
yarn start
```

Answer (score 0):

The error occurs, because the create-react-native-app is using the wrong version of **react-native-scripts**. It uses the last stable version of react-native-scripts, which is 2.01. This version does not contain the **init.js** file mentioned in the error message.

To fix the error, we need to use a version of react-native-scripts that is compatible with create-react-native-app. Version 1.4.0 of react-native-scripts seems to be compatible as it was released a few months after create-react-native-app.

So to create a new project using create-react-native-app, use the command: create-react-native-app --scripts-version 1.4.0 [project-name]. This solution worked with create-react-native-app version **1.0.0**

Answer (score -1):

You are probably looking at an old tutorial, there has been changes recently with react-native
https://github.com/react-community/create-react-native-app/issues/770

Comment: It probably is an old tutorial. New way to start a React Native app is here: https://github.com/react-community/create-react-native-app